# How to create a multi step form with conditional steps?

Tags: forms, wizard, multi-step

I am designing a highly complex form for creating a software company. We are yet to decide on if the form needs to be designed as a Wizard. The first step of the form will gather basic details and include some conditional fields. Based on the answers provided in the first step, we will determine whether the 2nd step needs to be shown or skipped, directing the user to the 3rd step instead. After completing the 3rd step, all previous steps should be allowed to be skipped.

However, the challenge lies in the fact that users can create a company at any step. Thus, we need to find a way to simplify the interface and improve the overall user experience.

Comment: I believe this is the second time you've asked this question, and I recall commenting on it before. Nevertheless, I'll address it again: If a user can interact at any step, how does this process become conditional? You mentioned that step 2 will be shown based on step 1 answers, which can also lead directly to step 3. In that case, how will users see Step 1 and/or Step 2 if they depend on the completion of Step 1? Do you have some kind of flow for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest understanding the problem for now. Identify:

- What you need to capture
- The most effective components to capture that information
- Dependencies (a flowchart would be useful here)

Based on this you can then understand natural groupings of content, and it should also identify any more issues such as the 'create a company at any step'. I would consider if you can do this early in the process and use that information to inform the presentation.